# PHP imap and folder name with space

Tags: php, imap

How to handle folder names which contains spaces?

In every function which requires folder name, im using string like that:

```
{server.address.com:port}"INBOX.abc def"
```

but it causes php to crash with:

```
Can't subscribe to mailbox "INBOX.abc def": no such mailbox
```

changing string to look like this:

```
{server.address.com:port}INBOX."abc def"
```

doesnt change anything, still error. How can i open/check/whatever folder with space in name?

**Edit:**
Question updated with a bit better error message

Combinations of folder strings which i tried:

- "INBOX.abc def" - fail,
- INBOX."abc def" - fail,
- \INBOX\abc def  - fail,
- "\INBOX\abc def" - fail

Answer (score 2):

Solved!

According to RFC3501, Mailbox Naming (5.1):

> Any character which is one of the atom-specials (see the Formal
>            Syntax) will require that the mailbox name be represented as a
>            quoted string or literal.

That includes space:

> atom-specials   = "(" / ")" / "{" / SP / CTL / list-wildcards /
>                     quoted-specials / resp-specials

so, the right folder string should be:

> {server}"INBOX.folder with spaces"

but in my case, correct string is.....

> {server}INBOX.folder with spaces

Dont know why, seems that PHPs imap functions are not fully compatible with RFC. Or just i cant read and understand rfc.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this sintax when you refer the directory:
 "\INBOX\folder with spaces"

So this solution gets "works on my machine" certificate. What error code do you get?

Comment: Not working. Im not getting anything else than a blank page and `PHP Fatal error:  Exception thrown without a stack frame in Unknown on line 0` entry in php error logs.

Comment: Maybe you will find the sollution here: http://www.compdigitec.com/labs/2009/08/02/solving-fatal-error-exception-thrown-without-a-stack-frame-in-unknown-on-line-0/

Answer (score 0):

"\INBOX\abc def" this is better but maybe your INBOX in in the wrong place!
It must be in the "htdocs" i think!
and you can acces only a file, not a folder!
 like: "\INBOX\abc def\file.txt"